# enableSelection and uiGridConstants

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm trying to get rows selectable only with a certain `$treeLevel`.
The console returned a `ReferenceError: uiGridConstants is not defined`.

I have to admit that I don't fully understand what uiGridConstants stands for.

Here is my code:

```
onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {

        this.gridApiBatches = gridApi;
        console.info(gridApi);

        gridApi.grid.options.enableSelection = function (row) {
            if (row.entity.$treeLevel != 3) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        };
        gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uiGridConstants` is module and you have to inject it as dependency into your controller just like you inject `$scope`.

Sample:

```
app.controller('SurveyReportController', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants',
    function($scope, uiGridConstants) {

        \\ your angular controller code here

    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you ! My code does not work but uiGridConstants is recognized :-)